# SQL For Each 'event' return Open/Close date/times

Tags: sql, for-loop

I have a table of events, some date/times, and revision numbers for each event.  The number of revisions vary.  Most events open, then things happen to cause revisions, then they close. Sometimes events open, things happen, the event closes, then it re-opens using the same event number, things happen .   .    .

There is no available table of events that tells me "at this time the event opened", "at this time the event was closed", "at this time the event was re-opened", etc.  That would be too easy.

The same event can open and close multiple times.
I want to create a report where a user can pick some date/time parameters and see what events are active (open) at that moment, or between two date/times. Here is an example of both an event that opens and closes three times, and an event that only opens and closes once, and what I desire for an output.  The results below are stored into a table variable called **@CEvents**.

[image]
[image]

It looks to me like the English version of the question is something like "If all of an event's **ClosedDateTime** values are NULL:

1. The **Created or reopened DT** = the **RevDateTime** value of the **MIN(rev_num);**
2. The **Closed DT** = the **RevDateTime** value of the **MAX(rev_num);**

If an event has one or more non-NULL **ClosedDateTime** values:

1. A **Created or reopened DT** = the **RevDateTime** value of the **MIN(rev_num);**
2. A **Closed DT** = the **RevDateTime** value for the row previous to the row where the
   **ClosedDateTime** is not NULL;
3. A **Created or reopened DT** = the **RevDateTime** value for the row right after the row where
   the **ClosedDateTime** is not NULL;
4. Repeat for each instance where there is a **ClosedDateTime** value;
5. Finish up with a **Closed DT** = the **RevDateTime** value of the **MAX(rev_num);**

I cannot figure out how to write the SQL for this question. Or, perhaps you have a better idea?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this to my satisfaction by building a temp table containing the cloumns I wanted and updating the table with a series of INSERT queries.

1. Each event's first rev_num was given an INT 'Status' value of 0, meaning open
2. Since there was a ClosedDT field a 'Status' value of -1 (closed) was added for each row that had one.
3. To get the "I'm back open again" values for those events with more than one open/close pair I used a query that joined the table upon itself by the rev_num to the copy of the table's rev_num + 1, thereby retrieving the timestamp value of the row after the CloseDT, which is the re-opened datetime:

```
    INSERT INTO @CEvents2
    SELECT a.ag_id, a.dgroup, a.num_1, a.RevDT TimeStamp, Status = 0, RowNum = NULL, a.eid
    FROM @CEvents a
    LEFT JOIN @CEvents b on a.num_1 = b.Num_1 and a.rev_num  = b.rev_num + 1
    WHERE b.ClosedDT is NOT NULL
```

4. To get a final closed date/time I used a summary table that contains the
   earliest and latest date/time for the event, choosing that one field that contained the latest date/time to insert as the timestamp.
5. I added one more field, a RowNum partitioning by the event number, ordering by the timestamp which resulted in a table that shows the chronology of each event and for each row a 0 (I'm open) and -1 (I'm closed).
   It just remains for the report user to pick a set of dates to see the chronology, or to pick a time and see which events are in a 0 status at that very moment.

I opted to forgo putting the results into a side-by-side table showing a column for Open and one for Close.  Instead each row has the open/close INT values of 0 or -1.